# Longest continuous pairs

Tags: python, list

1st pair's 1st element should be less than the 2nd pairs 1st element : same for 2nd elements individually in a sorted list of pairs.

```
xlist = [(3, 9), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 0)] # sorted by first element of pair

ylist = [(j,i) for i,j in (sorted([(y,x) for x,y in xlist]))] = [(6, 0), (4, 6), (5, 7), (3, 9)] # sorted by second element of pair
```

What I want is to find the longest pair that is continuous, i.e. `(4, 6), (5, 7)`

PS. there can be other continuous pairs like that, but is there a way to extract the longest continuous pairs?

(4, 6), (5, 7) is determined as the longest pair based on the fact that the next pair's 1st element(5) is less than current(4). The next pair's 2nd element(7) is less than current(6)  (Basically 5 > 4 and 6 > 7). And lets add another element to that list say (8, 10); this is added to the output sequence as well, as 8 > 5 and 10 > 7. So the longest pairs become (4, 6), (5, 7), (8, 10)

Comment: How `(4, 6), (5, 7)` is determined as the longest continuous pair?

Comment: You have to explain a bit more as to what you mean by continuous here and what you mean by longest here.

Comment: (4, 6), (5, 7) is determined as the longest pair based the on fact that the next pair's 1st element(5) is less than current(4). The next pair's 2nd element(7) is less than current(6). And lets add another element to that list say (8, 9), this is added to the output sequence as well, as 8>5 and 9>7. So the longest pairs become (4, 6), (5, 7), (8, 9)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the maximal common subsequence of the two lists, here a code using `difflib` that do what you want. I don't know exactly the implementation of `SequenceMatcher` but it seems quite optimized as it avoids for-loop in the whole lists:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

xlist = [(3, 9), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 0), (7, 8)]
ylist = [(6, 0), (4, 6), (5, 7), (7, 8), (3, 9)]

out = SequenceMatcher(None, xlist, ylist).get_matching_blocks()
max_block = max(out, key=lambda x: x.size)
start, end = max_block.a, max_block.a + max_block.size
out = xlist[start:end]
print(out)  # [(4, 6), (5, 7)]
```

If you mean the longest increasing sequence of the second coordinate in `xlist` (same as previously but allowing "skips" in sequence), you can go with:

```
xlist = [(3, 9), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 0), (7, 8)]

def find_lis_2nd_coord(pairs: List[Tuple]) -> List[Tuple]:
    """Find longest increasing subsequence (LIS).

    LIS is determined along 2nd coordinate of input pairs.
    """
    # lis[i] stores the longest increasing subsequence of sublist
    # `pairs[0…i][1]` that ends with `pairs[i][1]`
    lis = [[] for _ in range(len(pairs))]

    # lis[0] denotes the longest increasing subsequence ending at `pairs[0][1]`
    lis[0].append(pairs[0])

    # Start from the second element in the list
    for i in range(1, len(pairs)):
        # Do for each element in sublist `pairs[0…i-1][1]`
        for j in range(i):
            # Find the longest increasing subsequence that ends with
            # `pairs[j][1]` where it is less than the current element
            # `pairs[i][1]`
            if pairs[j][1] < pairs[i][1] and len(lis[j]) > len(lis[i]):
                lis[i] = lis[j].copy()

        # include `pairs[i]` in `lis[i]`
        lis[i].append(pairs[i])

    return max(lis, key=len)


print(find_lis_2nd_coord(xlist))  # [(4, 6), (5, 7), (7, 8)]
```

Disclaimer: this version is O(n^2) but I didn't find more optimized idea or implementation. At least it works.

Comment: Okay but would this work if there are 2 or more equal number of sequence.
for eg:- 
xlist = [(2, 0), (3, 5), (5, 3)]
ylist = [(2, 0), (5, 3), (3, 5)]                                                                                                                  

And prints the longest sequence found is 2 #where it either (2, 0), (5, 3) or (2, 0), (3, 5)

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what your are meaning by "continuous pair". I'm adding a section in my answer accordingly.